# Can't get statuses using koala for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, koala

I'm new to koala and FB graph.
I want my rails app to display all statuses from a fb page.
My code is:

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(APP_ID, APP_SECRET, nil)
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@oauth.get_app_access_token)
@statuses = @graph.get_connections('PAGE_ID', "statuses")
```

The error I get is:

```
Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: OAuthException, code: 100, message: (#100) Requires user session [HTTP 400]
```

I guess it's because I've got an APP_ID and not a user session but not sure how to fix.
Please help.

Comment: Where did you get `statuses` from?

Comment: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Graph-API#getting-public-data

Comment: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Acting-as-a-Page

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I got the statuses for graph docs. But no values are entered, instead I get the error.
I looked at the links but that is not the case since I don't manage to page, I need the info on many different pages.

Comment: So you can only get public feed contents & info, which is described under first link.

Comment: Yes but statuses are public as well. Can you help me with getting a user session? Must I do Facebook user login?

Comment: Man, those are basic things that you should be able to figure out from the docs. I'm not gonna write code for you.